# Gravitee - changing text from the API management portal

Tags: gravitee

I want to change the default "Unleash the power of your APIs" text on the portal's home page. Is there a way that I can do that via the API management portal (and not via the distribution folder files)?

I've just found the option on settings > theme to changes overall styles configs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do customisations on the portal page, such as changing the default text based on the information in this [documentation](https://docs.gravitee.io/apim/3.x/apim_installguide_portal_ui_configuration.html)